# Python - Populate a list by searching through a list of objects and seeing if they contain a specific value

Tags: python, list, keyerror

I'm trying to populate a list based on specific items listed within a list of objects. I'm struggling to find the right syntax to let me search through a list of objects to see if a list contained within those objects has a specific value or not.

Here is my list of objects:

```
my_list = [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "group": "Upper",
        "availability": [
            "Morning",
            "Afternoon",
            "Evening",
            "Night"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "group": "Upper",
        "availability": [
            "Evening",
            "Night"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "C",
        "group": "Lower",
        "availability": [
            "Morning"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to fill a new list with the name and group of any object that has "Morning" in the "availability" list.

I've looked up various different ways of populating lists, but I haven't found a way to populate a list based on whether a list within an object within a list contains a specific item.

!EDIT!
I tried using the list comprehension suggestion below and it seemed to work, but then I tried to apply it to populating my new list with both the name and group:

```
availability_list = [obj["name", "group"] for obj in my_list if "Morning" in obj["availability"]]
```

and I'm now getting the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
('name', 'group')
```

Comment: Use a list comprehension that performs the test you want. `'Morning' in item['availability']`

Comment: That's not JSON; it's just a list of `dict` objects. It might have *resulted* from a JSON-encoded string, but that's irrelevant once the string has been decoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want both the name and the group, just create a new dictionary and then add to a list as follow:

```
new_list = []
for obj in my_list:
    if "Morning" in obj['availability']:
        new_dict = {'name':obj['name'],'group':obj['group']}
        new_list.append( new_dict )
print( new_list )
```

with the following result:

```
[{'name': 'A', 'group': 'Upper'}, {'name': 'C', 'group': 'Lower'}]
```

If you really want the inline solution here it is, but never use this if you are a real programmer in a company. Its just appalling practise for maintainability and reusability:

```
new_list = [ ({'name':obj['name'],'group':obj['group']}) for obj in my_list if "Morning" in obj['availability'] ]
```

Comment: This works for the example I gave (which was considerably smaller than my actual codebase), but how would it work on something with more keys in the object? My actual code has 6 keys for each object (name, group, teamsize, availability, location, duration), but I only want the name, group and teamsize in the new list. I tried adding 'availability', 'location', 'duration' to the del new_list[-1] line, but that gives me another keyError exception for 'availability', 'location', 'duration'

Comment: it works now for any number of keys, but be warned, the inline version is not good practise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```py
available_in_morning = [obj["name"] for obj in my_list if "Morning" in obj["availability"]]
```